# Attempting to implement this recursive Fibonacci sequence gives wrong outputs

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86

I am trying to implement Fibonacci sequence in assembly by using recursion. This is my first time of trying to implement recursion in x86 Assembly.

The code compiles fine but it gives wrong outputs. The output for 1 is 1, output for 2 is 0, output for 3 is 1, output for 4 is 2, output for 5 is 3.

Only output it gives correct when you plug 5 in.

Is there something wrong with the algorithm?

```
.DATA
  n1 DWORD ?

  prompt1 BYTE "Please enter the first value", 0

  prompt3 BYTE "No negative numbers!",0
  string BYTE 40 DUP (?)
  resultLbl BYTE "The Fib is: ", 0
  fib BYTE 40 DUP (?), 0

  .CODE
  _MainProc PROC

    input prompt1, string, 40
    atod string
    test eax, eax 
    js signed 
    mov n1, eax

    jmp procName
    signed:
    output prompt3, string
    jmp end1

   procName:
     mov eax, n1
     push n1
     call fib1
     add esp,4


      dtoa fib, eax
      output resultLbl, fib
      end1:
       mov eax, 0
       ret

  _MainProc ENDP

  Fib1 proc
    PUSH EBP          ; save previous frame pointer
    MOV  EBP, ESP     ; set current frame pointer

    MOV  EAX, [EBP+8] ; get argument N
    CMP  EAX, 1       ; N<=1?
    JA   Recurse      ; no, compute it recursively
    MOV  ECX, 1       ; yes, Fib(1)--> 1
    JMP  exit

    Recurse:
     DEC  EAX          ; = N-1
     MOV  EDX, EAX     ; = N-1
     PUSH EDX          ; save N-1
     PUSH EAX          ; set argument = N-1
     CALL Fib1   ; compute Fib(N-1) to ECX
     POP  EAX          ; pop N-1
     DEC  EAX          ; = N-2
     PUSH ECX          ; save Fib(N-1)
     PUSH EAX          ; set argument = N-2
     CALL Fib1    ; compute Fib(N-2) to ECX
     POP  EAX          ; = Fib(N-1)
     ADD  ECX, EAX     ; = Fib(N-1)+FIB(N-2)
     exit:
      MOV  ESP,EBP      ; reset stack to value at function entry 
      POP  EBP          ; restore caller's frame pointer
      RET 
Fib1 endp

END
```

Comment: That's 32-bit code; it won't run on a real 8086.  Fixed that for you.

Comment: You left out info on what it does output for various inputs.  Seeing what actually happens instead of having to simulate it in our heads is very helpful for anyone that wanted to help you.  See [mcve].  Learn to use a debugger so you can single-step through your code and see what happens each step.

Comment: Added output in the edit.

Comment: `ADD  ECX, EAX` at the end looks suspicious.  Your caller seems to be expecting a return value in EAX for `dtoa fib, eax`, but your internal recursion produces a result in ECX.  Single-step in a debugger.  Also, you push twice before the last `call Fib1`, but only pop once after.  (So the `pop ebp` will get the value you pushed from ECX).  I'm surprised this doesn't crash; I guess nothing uses EBP after you return.  Like I said, use a debugger and watch registers change.

Comment: Will do, appreciate it

Comment: @PeterCordes - fib1 entry is `push ebp` | `mov ebp,esp`, and exit is `mov esp,ebp` | `pop ebp` , so even though there are 4 pushes but only 2 pops within the main part of fib, esp has been saved and restored using ebp at entry and exit.  Stack space will get consumed at a greater rate, by an extra 8 bytes per level of nesting, but fib(47) is the max value possible for 32 bit unsigned integers, and the practical limit is less since time complexity is O(2^n) for recursive Fibonacci.